# Windows security - store password safely with biometric framework

Tags: c#, windows, fingerprint, biometrics

Let's say I'd like to store and restore some secret data (password) onto/from the HDD in Windows 10.

For this purpose, because basically anyone can access to HDD, I want to use some cryptography.
I'm planning to use a symmetric-key algo, i.e one private key can encrypt and decrypt the data (password).

Now of course, this private key has to be kept in safe (not on HDD).
Here comes the Biometric Framework which can identify your fingerprint.

I've found a nice wrapper for C#: https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/WinBiometricDotNet,
but I'm still stuck, because I don't know how it can be used as a "private key".

For example, `WinBioIdentify` provides [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) after I touch the sensor, which is a Security Identifier, but I don't know if it's the right choice for private key.

So the question is simple, after identifying my fingerprint with Windows Biometric Framework, how shall I use that for encrypting/decrypting the password?

Comment: The private key implies the PKI infrastructure. As I understand, you need some stable identifiers. I'm not familiar with WBF but in case it returns the same SID for the concrete finger:) just encrypt your data with one of the symmetric algos.

Comment: Well, yes. SID is said to be *a unique, immutable identifier of a user* by its definition. This way it can be a nice choice for a symmetric algo. But the question is, if SID is right for this? I.e.: if SID is also presented in the registry somewhere, it won't meet the requirements.

Comment: Ok, it took 3 seconds to realize that SID is presented in the registry, and also can be queried by command line programs for a particular user. So it's out.